# Gevent backdoor inspect running code

Tags: python, python-2.7, gevent, inspect

I am using `gevent` with its `Backdoor` feature.

This is a simplified version of my code :

```
from gevent import backdoor, event

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stop_event = event.Event()
        self.servers = []
        self.servers.append(backdoor.BackdoorServer((localhost, 6666))
        # There is a tcp stream server using gevent configured too

    def start(self):
        for server in self.servers:
            if not server.started:
                server.start()
        self.stop_event.wait()
        for server in self.servers:
            if server.started:
                server.stop()


def run(*args, **kw):
    app = App()
    app.start()
```

The `run` method is called in a `console_scripts` created from the `entry_points` in my `setup.py`

I want to use my backdoor to inspect the `app` variable local in my `run` function.

I connect to the backdoor, and run the command `inspect.stack()`. This is what I am getting :

```
[
(<frame object at 0x7fa49ea0b3a0>, '<console>', 1, '<module>', None, None), 
(<frame object at 0x7fa49ce727f0>, '/usr/lib/python2.7/code.py', 103, 'runcode', ['            exec code in self.locals\n'], 0), 
(<frame object at 0x7fa49ce70250>, '/usr/lib/python2.7/code.py', 87, 'runsource', ['        self.runcode(code)\n'], 0), 
(<frame object at 0x7fa49ced7d38>, '/usr/lib/python2.7/code.py', 265, 'push', ['        more = self.runsource(source, self.filename)\n'], 0), 
(<frame object at 0x3569a40>, '/usr/lib/python2.7/code.py', 243, 'interact', ['                    more = self.push(line)\n'], 0), 
(<frame object at 0x7fa49ced39b0>, 'path_to_project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent-1.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/backdoor.py', 75, '_run', ['                console.interact(banner=self.banner)\n'], 0),
(<frame object at 0x7fa49ced3b90>, 'path_to_project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent-1.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/gevent/greenlet.py', 327, 'run', ['                result = self._run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)\n'], 0)
]
```

As you can see, it seems that gevent is rewriting the stack. The `run` function from my module which is starting the program is not in it. It stops at the run method of the greenlet executing the backdoor.

Is there any way to access the running `run` method which has started the program in order to inspect it and access its local `app` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. The `greenlet` object has a `parent` attribute to find which one has spawned the one you are currently looking at. Then the greenlet has an attribute `gr_frame` to store the stacktrace.

So in my case, once I am connected to the backdoor server, it would be something like that :

```
>>> import greenlet, inspect
>>> greenlet.getcurrent()
<SocketConsole at 0x7fca7122d190>

>>> greenlet.getcurrent().parent
<Hub at 0x7fca71560050 epoll default pending=0 ref=4 fileno=3 resolver=<gevent.resolver_thread.Resolver at 0x7fca7126a510 pool=<ThreadPool at 0x7fca7127fe10 0/1/10>> threadpool=<ThreadPool at 0x7fca7127fe10 0/1/10>>

>>> greenlet.getcurrent().parent.parent
<greenlet.greenlet object at 0x7fca7d9be690>

>>> inspect.getouterframes(greenlet.getcurrent().parent.parent.gr_frame)
[
...
(<frame object at 0x174ac40>, 'path_to_project/endpoints/app.py', 238, 'run', ['        app.start()\n'], 0),
...
]

>>> inspect.getouterframes(greenlet.getcurrent().parent.parent.gr_frame)[4][0]
<frame object at 0x174ac40>

>>> inspect.getargvalues(inspect.getouterframes(greenlet.getcurrent().parent.parent.gr_frame)[4][0]).locals 
{'args': [], 'app': <endpoints.app.App object at 0x7fca71360190>, 'kw': {}}

>>> inspect.getargvalues(inspect.getouterframes(greenlet.getcurrent().parent.parent.gr_frame)[4][0]).locals['app']
<endpoints.app.App object at 0x7fca71360190>
```

I have noow access to the local object `app` inside the running function `run` to inspect the value of its other attributes and debug my live gevent application.